# How Do I change the size of a Window that a Custom .Desktop Launcher Defaults to?

Tags: gnome, launcher

I've created a custom Chrome application shortcut for a webapp that I need to use. Is there a way to control its size (height/width) and/or placement. I was thinking that this might be an option in the .desktop file, but can't seem to figure out where this might be configured.

I'm using 13.10 with Gnome-Shell

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Chrome installed, so I'll quote "allyourcode" from this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/306992/is-there-a-way-to-start-multiple-applications-at-once-and-arrange-their-windows) :

> Chrome has `--window-size=width,height`:
>   [code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27550](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=27550) That thread also
>   claims that `--window-position` also exists, but it doesn't work for me.
>   Found someone else for whom --window-position doesn't work:
>   [productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/79i1oLYhK8g](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/79i1oLYhK8g)

Always remember to check the help or the user's manual from the applications you're running : 
`man google-chrome` or `google-chrome --help` (sometimes even `google-chrome -h`). The answers are usually somewhere in there (I can't check myself, I repeat : I don't use Chrome).

---

The usual command should be the [X standard](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/man/man7/X.7.xhtml#heading7) `--geometry=wxh+x+y` but it wasn't implemented in 2012 yet. Worth the try today though.

Placement in X standards are :

```
+0+0 : upper left hand corner.
−0+0 : upper right hand corner.
−0−0 : lower right hand corner. 
+0−0 : lower left hand corner.
```

So, let's say an app should be 100 pixel by 100 pixel, on the top right corner, the command would be :

```
applicationname --geometry=100x100-0-0
```

---

**NOTE** : these are options you'll need to add to the `Exec=` command in the *.desktop* file, not a specific line. You can test these in your terminal direclty.